# Paypal Cancelation - Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have googled this for a while and I don't think I was able to get a clear cut answer.

We have an application that displays a Subscribe button. Once clicked, It takes the user to the Paypal website where s/he can complete the txn.

Later on, Paypal sends an IPN to our site indicating whether payment was successful. This integration is done by setting hidden html variables.

Now, there is a need to allow the user to cancel their subscription. So far, most of my readings indicate that the user **must** login to paypal and manage his/her subscription there.

In addition to that, I was able to find some other people mentioning that It would work with using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

The problem is that the later requires **ProfileId** which is returned thru CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. it looks like there is a gap. I would appreciate if somebody can pinpoint to the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Try using the subscription ID as the ProfileId.

Comment: I read that it is a hit miss

Comment: Sorry, I think I had another question on my mind.  Try using the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API, and pass in the subscription ID of the subscription in the ProfileId parameter.